# Ionic 2 App Conflict "Public" vs "Public Static"

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

I'm an amateur to this thing, tryin' to code an app and I found conflictin' parts on my code. I don't have a clean code just makin' things work, I tried it out like this:

```
    constructor(platform: Platform, public nativeStorage: NativeStorage) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.nativeStorage.getItem('NoTaleDB').then(function (json) {
    if (json) {
      GlobalVariables.novelList = JSON.parse(json);
    }
    });
    });
    }

    public static save() {
    this.nativeStorage.setItem('NoTaleDB', JSON.stringify(GlobalVariables.novelList)).then(() => {}, () => {});
}
```

And got this error:

```
Property 'nativeStorage' does not exist on type 'typeof StorageService'
```

When I modify the function into this:

```
public save() {
    this.nativeStorage.setItem('NoTaleDB', JSON.stringify(GlobalVariables.novelList)).then(() => {}, () => {});
}
```

It finds the nativeStorage but I get this error instead from Pages and the service itself:

```
Property 'save' does not exist on type 'typeof StorageService'.
```

I've been tryin' to finish this app for a long time now but ends up only tryin' to fix bugs. Please, provide a simple solution, something a newbie can understand. Thanks. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want the function *body* for this to function:

```
public static save() {
    this.nativeStorage.setItem('NoTaleDB', JSON.stringify(GlobalVariables.novelList)).then(() => {}, () => {})
}
```

`this` is *not* available for *static* member as static members exit on the *class* and not the instance (the thing referenced by `this`).

## Fixed code

Has to be :

```
public save() {
        this.nativeStorage.setItem('NoTaleDB', JSON.stringify(GlobalVariables.novelList)).then(() => {}, () => {})
    }
```

Now you *are* getting the error:

> Property 'save' does not exist on type 'typeof StorageService'.

You are calling `StorageService.save`. This is wrong. You should be calling `save` on an instance e.g.

```
new StoargeService(pass in the stuff it needs).save(); // Works now
```

## More

Some docs on TypeScript classes : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/classes.html

Comment: Thanks. <3 I'm still getting this btw, am I doing it right?:
`[07:35:37]  typescript: src/pages/new/new.ts, line: 49 
            Property 'save' does not exist on type 'typeof StorageService'. 

      L48:  GlobalVariables.novelList[this.titleIndex].Summary = this.novelSummary;
      L49:  new StorageService.save();
      L50:  let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({

[07:35:37]  typescript: src/services/storage.service.ts, line: 15 
            Property 'save' does not exist on type 'typeof StorageService'. 

      L14:  });
      L15:  new StorageService.save();`

Comment: You have code `L15: new StorageService.save()`. I have code `new StoargeService(pass in the stuff it needs).save()`. Not the same. The code I posted is the correct way 